# How to run javascript tests for node.js project on gated check in?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, ntvs

I've added node.js project to solution. Now I need js tests to be discovered and run on gated check-in.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using XAML build or vNext build? Please share your build steps here.

Comment: XAML. We use Typemock and it doesn't work with vNext yet.
What I know is that build returns the following error:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (136): Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\Wumte.WebClient.Frontend.Tests.exe" because it was not found.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Do you need the whole XAML?

Comment: No need to share the XAML definition now. Have you customized your build process template to use Typemock?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT This file is provided by Typemock itself. Disclaimer: Actually, I'am not experienced with ALM part of TFS. What is the general idea of running JS  tests along with usual mstests. Should it be two different test runs?

Answer (score 0):

Typemock supports integrate with both XAML build and vNext build in Team Foundation Server 2015. Check this link for more details: http://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fintegratingwithteamfoundationserver2015.htm

If you want to use Typemock in XAML build, you can either [Configuring the Typemock Isolator Template](http://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fstep3configuringthetypemockisolatortemplate2015.htm), or [Using Typemock Tasks in your Custom Template](http://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Faddingtypemockisolatortasks.htm).

Comment: This doc is irrelevant for TFS2015 upd.2